# Cloning a css style from a style sheet using jquery/greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, css, greasemonkey

I am writing a Greasemonkey script using jquery, and I want to add information from multiple pages, but the object i want to load is a div with an Id, is there any way I can retrieve the style information, so that I can apply it to the added sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [getComputedStyle()](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/windowmethods.shtml)

This is untested, but the code would be something like this:

```
var someOtherElement = document.getElementById('blah');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myId'), '');
for (var i in style) {
    if (style.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        someOtherElement.style[i] = style[i];
    }
}
```

This will only work (well, *this* probably doesn't work at all, but the basic idea of it will only work) with Firefox, but since you said you're using greasemonkey, I assume that's not a concern for you.

---

I think my brain isn't working properly this morning - but in any case, here's something which works, but in a dodgy way. Loop through the styles of the element you are copying them *to*.

```
var s = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myElement'), null);
var someOtherElement = document.getElementById('someOther');

for (var i in someOtherElement.style) {
    try {
        someOtherElement.style[i] = s[i];
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

Like I said, my brain is not working and the above is dodgy. The `style` object has properties `length` and `parentRule` which are read-only which makes it die, hence the try/catch.

Comment: The "window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myId'), '');" is working just fine, but I don't think it is coming across as an array. 
If I call something like "alert(style.backgroundColor);" it displays the style, but if I try the "for (var i in style){" and try to do anything in the for loop, it does nothing.